Metal Shader in SpriteKit
I am trying to render a red square using a Metal shader in SpriteKit.  Instead I get a white square based on the color I supply when instantiating the SKSpriteNode.  Using a default constructor and then setting the size of the sprite node renders a black square.
What am I doing wrong?
I am running in Xcode 15.4, using iOS 17.0 in simulator.
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var scene: SKScene {
        // Create the `GameScene` and set its properties.
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300) // Set the scene size.
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Embed the `SpriteView` in the SwiftUI view.
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400) // Set the frame size of the SwiftUI view.
            .padding()
            .background(Color.orange)
            .ignoresSafeArea() // Ignore safe areas to allow full screen rendering.
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        self.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        
        self.backgroundColor = .green
        
        self.size.width = 200
        self.size.height = 200
        
        view.allowsTransparency = true
        
        // Inline Metal fragment shader to render a solid red color.
        let fragmentShaderSource = """
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

// Basic fragment function to output red color.
fragment float4 fragment_main() {
    return float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Red color with full opacity.
}
"""

        // Create the Metal shader in `SpriteKit` using only the fragment function.
        let metalShader = SKShader(source: fragmentShaderSource)

        // Create an `SKSpriteNode`.
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
        sprite.blendMode = .replace // Ensure the shader fully replaces the color.

        sprite.texture = nil
        
        // Apply the Metal shader to the sprite.
        sprite.shader = metalShader

        // Add the sprite to the scene.
        addChild(sprite)
    }
}

The result I get is:


if you're flexible you might consider using glsl instead of metal. void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1); } will work

The idea is to figure out how to use a Metal shader.

@Fault I get a runtime error when using this GLSL shader: Compiler failed to build request.  Probably because build settings are set to use Metal.  Not sure how to reset this.

Did you figure out how to use a Metal shader?

SKShader documentation says: "An SKShader object holds a custom OpenGL ES fragment shader.". Why do you think the metal shader code will work?
